# How much Sin per NPC?

Tags: dark-souls

So there I was one day trotting along in my [**Elite Knight Set**](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Elite_Knight_Set) in Undead Parish to visit the blacksmith. I goto talk to him, and me been stupid with my 'habits', I press every button on my controller in a spasm, (xD) and nearly kill him with my +10 Great Scythe. Went to Oswald up the tower, and had to pay a whopping 180,000 souls to cleanse myself of Sin.

**Is there any set amount of Sin you obtain from killing certain (friendly) NPC's? Modifiers?**

Also, while I'm at it, I beat Quelaag and went to visit her sister, thinking that [**Eingyi**](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/eingyi) was a normal enemy, I whacked him and he died... Will I get Sin for killing him? I don't want to pay another 180,000 because I killed Worm Boy who sells his useless (for my character) pyromancies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is separate sin for PvP and for PvE. While PvP sin is calculated in points and can not be absolved by Oswald, PvE sin has no calculation: You are either a sinner or you are not.

Every PvE sin committed will instantly make you a sinner and will require you to pay Oswald. The amount of souls you need to absolve your sins is determined by your level. For each level you need 500 souls, so at level 360 you need to pay 180000 souls.

[According to wikidot](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/sin), actions that result in PvE sin are:

> Anything that causes disapproval from an NPC or covenant, that requires Absolution to fix:
>
> - Making an NPC hostile, or killing them
> - Angering Gwyndolin by trespassing beyond the Darkmoon Tomb fog gate
> - Angering Alvina
> - Attacking Crossbreed Priscilla
>
> The only kind of PvE sin that cannot be removed is the kind that is obtained by destroying the illusion of Gwynevere. Although Oswald will allow the player to pay for its absolution, it will refresh and be placed upon the player again automatically.

Regarding Eingyi, I'm not sure if he is counted as an NPC or an egg carrier enemy, as according to [his wikidot page](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/eingyi), killing him doesn't break the covenant. However, if Oswald charges you again, you will have to pay the full amount again, or more if you leveled up since (although at that high a level the souls shouldn't be too hard to come by).

In any way, the different types of sin also have different penalties. The only penalty for PvE sin is that the angered NPC will attack you, and that you can be invaded in Dark Anor Londo after killing Gwynevere. You will *not* be added to the Book of the Guilty (like you would for getting PvP sin), so you can't be invaded by Darkmoon blades for having PvE sin.

Since you already killed Eingyi, there is no difference if you absolve or not, except for a clear conscience.

Comment: Well um... Very close, I was actually **Level 36** xD Maybe 5000 per level. Still, pretty harsh. Ill have to go ask Oswald to see if Eingyi is counted and will get back to you. Thanks for the answer. I understand now.

Comment: Also, @Kodama, I heard that when I enter NG+, my PvE Sin is cleansed. Is that true? And is it the same with PvP Sin? If not, how do I cleanse PvP Sin? (Haven't invaded yet)

Comment: Hmm... then the wiki seems to be wrong. The wikia wiki claims it's 1000 per level. Maybe it was changed to 5000 at some point. I didn't recall having to pay that much when I last played. The wikis tend to have some false information now and again though. You can lower PvP sin by getting killed by Darkmoon blade players (blue phantoms). Sinning by getting indicted after invasion increases your count by 1 and getting killed lowers it by 1.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I do think sin gets reset in ng+, at least the PvE sin. It's been quite some time since I last played it, so I'm not certain. If you want to know about the ng+ sin you could ask another question. Someone else will surely know :)

Comment: No, thats fine. I'm only up to Sen's Fortress so I'll probably ask at the end before I go murdering everyone for loot. >:) As for the souls, I just added a zero to what you said (500) so it lowers my level by a zero. (Hope you understand)
But seriously... I've seen top indicted and it's like 500,000 PvP Sin. Those hacks...